# Writing the automorphic form $\phi_f$ of a newform $f$ as a pure tensor

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the adele ring of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $f\in S_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)$ (possibly a newform) and $\phi_f:\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})\to \mathbb{C}$ be its cuspidal automorphic representation. I will define $\phi_f$ as follows. For $g\in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})$, we have the decomposition $g=\gamma hu$ where $\gamma\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$, $h\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})^+$, $u\in U_0(N)$ where
$$ U_0(N) := \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in\text{GL}_2(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}) \huge\mid\normalsize c\in N\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \right\}.$$
Then, we may define
$$ \phi_f(g) = \phi_f(\gamma hu):= (\det h)^{k/2}j(h,i)^{-k}f(hi)\omega_\chi(u) $$
where $\omega_\chi$ is the adelization of $\chi$ to $U_0(N)$. It can be checked this definition is well-defined.

The space of irreducible cuspidal automorphic representations can be decomposed into a restricted tensor product over the local places of $\mathbb{Q}$. I believe $\phi_f$ actually corresponds to a pure tensor. Is there a good way to see how to decompose
$$ \phi_f = \bigotimes_v' \phi_{v} = \phi_\infty \otimes \bigotimes_{p}' \phi_p ?$$

Comment: Why would $\phi_f$ be a pure tensor?

Comment: Is there a way to write it as a sum of pure tensors? I might be wrong about it being a pure tensor.

Comment: If it's a newform, then it's a pure tensor. Otherwise it's a finite linear combination of pure tensors.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Is there a nice way to see this for a newform (and what fails if my form isn't new)?

Comment: Have you read Gelbart's book or Goldfeld-Hundley? You have to go via the global Whittaker function and local Whittaker function. Oldforms are also pure tensors, but cusp forms can be linear combinations of various newforms and oldforms not lying in the same automorphic representation.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Your last sentence makes sense. I've been using Gelbart; can you refer me to the section where he talks about this? (I also wouldn't mind looking into Goldfeld-Hundley)

Comment: @PeterHumphries The OP wrote alternatively that $\phi_f$ is the automorphic representation and form, but isn't $\pi_f$ (having a local decomposition) the representation acting by shift on the Hilbert space generated by the translates of $\phi_f$?

Comment: @reuns Sorry, that’s my mistake. I meant to say $\phi_f$ is an automorphic form (generating the representation $\pi_f$)